# How to increase counter on repetition of value under an array mongodb

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a mongoose schema like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7acda13b808dbed05d6505"),
    "symbol" : "@AKS",
    "counter" : 4
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7acda13b808dbed05d6506"),
    "symbol" : "@AKD",
    "counter" : 5
}
```

Now if I want to update multiple column i.e "symbol" values on one query then MongoDB updateMany Query will do. This is Query:

```
MyCollectionName.updateMany({ 'symbol' : { $in : req.body.array}}, { $inc : { 'counter': 1 } }, function(err, data) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log('error')
                } else {
                    console.log('value incremented')
                }
            });
```

By this Query If I give the Array value i.e

```
var array = ["@AKS", "@AKD"];
```

Then it will Increment the counter of Both. My Question is If I will Provide the Same value on an array then I want Two increment not one. Like this:

```
var array = ["@AKS", "@AKS"];
//I want the Increment of 2.
var array = [@AKS", "@AKS", "@AKS", "@AKS"]
//at this stage I want the counter of Increment is 4
```

But currently it will do Only One.  Is this possible????
Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[`bulkWrite`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#bulkwrite_bulkWrite)** API for this update as it allows you to compose an array of **[`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)** write operations in which you can use the [**`updateOne`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#bulkwrite-write-operations-updateonemany) operation for each element in the array. The following example shows how you can apply it in your case:

```
let ops = [];
const handleResult = res => console.log(res);
const handleError = err => console.error(err);

req.body.array.forEach(function(item) {
    ops.push({
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": { "symbol": item },
            "update": { "$inc": { "counter": 1 } }
        }
    });

    if (ops.length === 1000) {
        MyCollectionName.bulkWrite(ops).then(handleResult).catch(handleError);
        ops = [];
    }
})

if (ops.length > 0)  MyCollectionName.bulkWrite(ops).then(handleResult).catch(handleError);
```

Answer (score 0):

what if instead of using `updateMany` you just `forEach` your array:

```
const yourArray = req.body.array;
yourArray.forEach(function(item) {
   MyCollectionName.update({ 'symbol': { $in: item }}, { $inc: { 'counter': 1 }, function (err, data) {
    // additional code
  }); 
});
```